# innerhtml in a neat way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I am using html and js, and I want to display a chunk of html code if the user clicks something. The code is a bit big so using `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =` is not attractive. I googled and found out about IFrame, but I want to avoid scroll bars and stuff, I hoped I could use a simple div, how can I do that? I am using jquery as well, I know about the hide() function in jquery, but the thing is that the stuff in the div with id display should change dynamically, so if the user clicks item1 he should get text1, item2 should get text2, and i want to have a specific place for textx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like

```
$('.ShowLink').click(function() { 
    $('#' + this.rel).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

This will toggle the element with the ID specified by the `rel=` attribute of each element with the `ShowLink` class.
For example:

```
<a href="#" rel="Text1" class="ShowLink">Show something</a>
...
<div id="Text1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML method is probably best performance-wise. If you don't retrieve additional content (for example through AJAX calls), put all blocks inside separate divs in advance, and set their "display" css attribute to "none". Then you can trigger attribute change for particular div to "block" with an event attached to some button or link.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by absolutely positioning several divs on top of each other, then showing/hiding the appropriate ones based on user input.  This way you don't need to manipulate the content of the elements, just show/hide them. The trick is to absolutely position the elements though.  If you do this, you may want to have the *last* div in the list to be statically positioned (assuming they will all be the same size) so that the rest of the page flows around those elements appropriately. Alternatively you could place all of these elements inside another div that is statically positioned that reserves the space for the absolutely positioned elements.